# JavaScript & File upload input field

Tags: javascript, file, input

i have 2 issue about file input hope that you guys can help .

1-  select the text of file input field :

`<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" >`

usually i do so by using : `document.getElementById("userfile").value`

but it doesnt work with Files .

2- update field value of file input. same as above , ususally i use :

`document.getElementById("userfile").value =  'C:\Users\me\Pictures\pic.jpg';`

i want that picture to be the selected value of a file input , but i cant do so .
anyhelp please .. ?

Comment: You can't do that, in any way or form, as the file input has some security restrictions, one of them being that you can't specify files on the users computer to upload.

Comment: You can do 1 if the browser already has support for it. You can't do 2. Read up on the HTML5 File API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, you can't specify a file from JavaScript that points to the user's file system. The browser won't allow you to do so. If this was possible, people would be exposing their files to websites, which could upload their private data without users knowing about it.

For your second question, if you want to access the image that the **user** has selected, you can use this [Bootstrap plugin](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/2.3.1/javascript.html#fileupload) to get to the image data from a file input *once the user has specified a file*.

Comment: thank you for help , that's why i could find a way to do so .. :/